# which Media Player reached its end, and different set of orders on the onCompletion() method

Tags: android, methods, android-mediaplayer

Lets say I have several players I've created.
And Lets say that for each one of them, I want a different set on actions to be activated.

How can I locate which player has been finished (the implementation itself of the case sentence) in order to act differently for each player ?

For example: in order to handle a single player, all we have to do is to implement the `onCompletion()` method like this:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
    //DO SOMETHING HERE THAT FITS FOR ALL KINDS OF PLAYER'S TYPE OBJECTS
}
```

How do I add a case sentence to expand it to handle several different player objects ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MediaPlayer` attribute passed to this method is the same `MediaPlayer` that has just completed, so as long as you are keeping a pointer to each media player (such as through a global variable), then all you need to do is check which media player you have received:

```
public class MyClass implements OnClompleteListener 
{
    MediaPlayer player1, player2, player3;
    //initialize them
    player1.setOnCompleteListener(this);
    player2.setOnCompleteListener(this);
    player3.setOnCompleteListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        if (mp == player1)
        {
            //TODO handle player 1 completion
        }
        else if (mp == player2)
        {
            //TODO handle player 2 completion
        }
        else if (mp == player3)
        {
            //TODO handle player 3 completion
        }
    }
}
```

You can also handle this in-line, without implementing the `OnCompleteListener`:

```
player1.setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        //mp IS ALWAYS EQUAL TO player1!
    }
});
```

Comment: @Adam, yes. That is all you need :)

Comment: 1. Can I just compare 2 objects just like that ?! 
2. Is there a simpler way to do so in the original onCompletion() method like we can do on the onClick with the case on the view event ?

Comment: @Adam, I added an example of handling the completion listener in-line, which I think is what you meant by question 2.

Comment: Now I understood :) , another question: I learned that in Java you can't just compare even a same type of objects just like vars with '==', you need to implement an equal() or compare every organ, But here you just == compare them, how-come ?

Comment: For complex Objects, `==` will return true if the two Objects in comparison are the same Object in memory - that is stored at the same memory location.

Comment: In Android, listeners such as OnClickListener, OnCompletionListener, etc, often return the Object that it is the callback for, but you will need to check documentation to be sure. Here is the documentation for OnCompletionListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html#onCompletion(android.media.MediaPlayer)

Comment: You mean that because Java methods gets the objects itself, the comparison will compare memory addresses which should be the same because this is EXACTLY the same object as we actually compare the right one to himself ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a class that extends `MediaPlayer` and give it an attribute like a number to keep track of which player is which.  Then you would check the player's number in the `onCompletion()` method.  Otherwise, you could create different onCompletion listeners and set them to the different players.

Comment: Is there something simpler like: switch(mp.getId()){....} like on the onClick() method ?

Comment: you should look at the MediaPlayer attributes since that is what is being passed to you. if there is no goo attribute, create one.